# Getting Output From PHP Script With LibcURL C++

Tags: php, c++, curl, libcurl

I am currently using libcurl to connect to my website, which runs a PHP script to check credentials that were sent through 'Post Data'. So far, I've got it to echo if the credentials were correct through the C++ console. What my question is, is if I can instead have the PHP script return a value to libcurl instead of printing to console.

Comment: This isn't really a PHP script question. PHP is not printing to the console - PHP just returns content to libcurl. It's up to your C++ code and how you use libcurl to determine how to handle the response data. The curl execution (e.g. curl_easy_perform) should return a result with the data. Either way, make sure you post your code and remove the php tag from the question.

Comment: You probably want to look into `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` and
`CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` if you are using the `curl_easy_setopt` way of setting up your POSTs.

Comment: @jhilgeman ok, but how do I get the PHP script to return anything? It doesn't seem to matter what I put in the return statement.

Comment: The PHP script just needs to echo its content normally. There's nothing special PHP (or any other remote script) needs to do. It's cURL's job to capture that output into a buffer and make it available to your code.

Comment: @jhilgeman how would I do that?

Comment: As I said before, start by posting what code you have.